# Replace data from Array based on the Id

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array :

```
mainArray = 
[
{name : "Eminem", id : 2},
{name : "Rakim" , id : 3 },
{name : "Kuniva", id : 4 }
]
```

Suppose I edit the **name** "Kuniva" and replace it with "Proof" and send the it to the database, and I get a json back like this :

```
[
{name : "Proof", id : 4 }
]
```

Is there a way for me to *replace* the old object in the mainArray with the updated Object using the id.

p.s I am displaying the names as expansion panels, so I can get the id of object that I click on. 
Please ask if any more clarification is required.

Comment: Do you mean you want to merge the data by `id`? This is assuming that the ID of the users don't change :)

Comment: It would be better to just use the returned JSON as the source of truth and override the value of mainArray with it. This way you are always in sync with your database. This would just be variable assignment `this.mainArray = returnedJson`

Comment: @Sam I agree with you: since you're returning the entire array anyway, it is better to treat the server as the singular source of truth.

Comment: @Sam I made a mistake in the question. Updated it.

Comment: use filter() Array Method in JavaScriptvar like ` newArray = array.filter(function(item) {
  return condition;
});`

Comment: @MenimE So you want to update "Kuniva" instead of "Proof" by id "4" ?

Comment: @HarshalYelpale https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gr4kci please refer to this. It makes more sense than this question. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can something like this.

```
mainArray = 
[
{name : "Eminem", id : 2},
{name : "Rakim" , id : 3 },
{name : "Kuniva", id : 4 }
];

var newObj = [
{name : "Proof", id : 4 }
][0];

var updatedIndex = mainArray.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === newObj.id);
mainArray[updatedIndex] = newObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
this.mainArray.find(item => item.id == 4).name = "Proof"
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4vvuqt?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Would you please take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gr4kci and let me know if your solution will work for this

Comment: Yes, it will work, check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7eb8xr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Right, but couple of questions. 1. Do I need to hardcode the name and 2. What about the rest of the updated values.

Comment: No, as per your requirement, you need to add logic so that you don'y have to hardcode the name, like adding a textbox

Answer (score 0):

It is might be easier to use `Map()` in this case.
Create a map like:

```
    const mainArrayMap = new Map(mainArray.map(user => [user.id, user]));
```

And after updation it can be set as

```
    const newVal = [{name : "Proof", id : 4 }];
    newVal.forEach(val => mainArrayMap.set(val.id, val));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. Be aware we are mutating the array.

```
const mainArray = [
  {name : "Eminem", id : 2},
  {name : "Rakim" , id : 3 },
  {name : "Kuniva", id : 4 }
]


const arrayFromDB = [
  {name : "Proof", id : 4 }
]

// Update the main array with entries from db
arrayFromDB.map(item=>{
  const index = mainArray.findIndex(value => value.id === item.id)
  mainArray[index] = item
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` collection to have `O(1)` while accessing to the desired element when you `map` your elements:

```
const unique = new Map(replaceArray.map(user => [user.id, user.name]))
const result = mainArray.map(({id, name}) => ({ id, name: unique.get(id) || name }));
```

An example:

```js
let mainArray =
    [
        { name: "Eminem", id: 2 },
        { name: "Rakim", id: 3 },
        { name: "Kuniva", id: 4 }
    ]

let replaceArray = [
    { name: "Proof", id: 4 }
]

const unique = new Map(replaceArray.map(user => [user.id, user.name]))
const result = mainArray.map(({id, name}) => ({ id, name: unique.get(id) || name }));    
console.log(result);
```